# Send an attach mail from Google Cloud Storage using App Enging Java Client

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

I want suggestions for sending mail with attachments from Google Cloud Storage.

Currently I upload a file(.mp3) in Google Cloud Storage within the specific bucket using App Engine Java Client.

I want to send this file (.mp3) as an attachment with the mail and mail will be send from another Java Web Application which is connected to Google Cloud Storage using App Engine Java Client.

As mentioned by Nick in an earlier post, I go through SendGrid documentation but can't find a suitable documentation about how to attach an file with mail and send.

Can you please help me what should be the best way ?

-DEV

Comment: Who's Nick? Reference? Sendgrid web api or SMTP API? What have you tried? You need to read the whole file from cloud storage before you can send it as an attachment.

Comment: btw, it's not necessary to use SendGrid. Appengine provides a Service for mails

Comment: Thanks All for your reply Konqi and Igor.Actually Nick is from Cloud Support. Can you please provide a link from where i can get idea or Start with attached mail.

Comment: you could start from official docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail_with_attachments

Answer (score 0):

`MimeBodyPart` has the `attachFile` function.

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile(java.lang.String)).